# Nav menu toggle sliding effect working repetedly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

My website `nav-menu` uses `slideToggle` function in the mobile menu.It has a slide toggler which controls the open/close of menu.One of the menu has a `sub-menu` . When clicking on that menu having sub-menu(Contains `ul`) the sub-menu open and closes and opens 4/5 times and then it closes.

### My codes are

```
<span class="menu-toggler"></span>
<ul class="nav-menu align-right">
  <li class="current"><a href="index.html#header">home</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html#about-us">about us</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html#services">services</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html#works">works</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html#team">team</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html#blog">Blog</a></li>
  <li>
      <a href="#" class="extra">Extra</a>
      <ul>
          <li><a href="blog-three.html">blog grid 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="blog-four.html">blog grid 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="blog-single.html">blog single</a></li>
          <li><a href="portfolio-three.html">portfolio 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="portfolio-single.html">portfolio single</a></li>
       </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="index.html#contact">contact</a></li>
   <li><a href="" class="search-bar extra"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

And my js

```
$(document).on('click', '.menu-toggler' ,function(e){
   $('.nav-menu').slideToggle();
   $('.menu-toggler').toggleClass('open');
});

if($('.nav-menu li').find('ul')){
   $('.nav-menu li ul').addClass('drop-menu');
}

$(window).on('load resize', function(){
        if($(window).width() < 1000){
            $('.drop-menu').parent('li').find('a').on('click', function(){
                $('.drop-menu').slideToggle();
            })
        }
    })
```

How can i stop repetating sliding of the sub-menu

Answer (score 0):

It might be reading multiple clicks. Just do a slide down function on click and hide the menu with a separate function.

```
$(document).on('click', '.menu-toggler' ,function(e){
   $('.nav-menu').slideDown();
   $('.menu-toggler').toggleClass('open');
});

$('.open').on('click',function(){
$('.nav-menu').hide();
});
```

Comment: its on submenu:  `if($('.nav-menu li').find('ul')){
   $('.nav-menu li ul').addClass('drop-menu');
}`

Comment: Just break it down. Make a function for OpenMenu() and CloseMenu() and tie them to the onclick calls then call the jquery slide functions in each of those. That should break things down a bit.